# Can I use Google Drive as a substitute for amazon s3 for my android app?

Tags: android, amazon-s3, google-drive-api

I'm doing a kinda music app where user can send edited songs to other users. Normally when the user send the song first the song uploaded to s3 and then the destination user downloads from it. Instead of s3 can I use the corresponding users drive and save the song in it and sending the link of that song. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

Here is some info about how to do it programmatically:
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/

Anyway, If you expect a lot of users for your application, it's better to use S3 because it's more scalable and better suits for high load systems.

Comment: Thanks. Drive suits me. Because I'm a student and doing the app for entertainment.

Comment: Drive will scale perfectly fine for this case because you are using the user's drive and not a central drive account, so not really true that S3 (or google cloud storage) would scale better.